# Subclass attribute in WHERE statement of a superclass

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-2.1

I use [class table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) for some tables in my symfony2 projects database. I've some relation tables with a foreign key to my superclass.

Now I want to write a query that starts in my relation table and joins the superclass. If I want to filter the records to the subclass I only need to write this:

```
SELECT r, c
FROM
BasicBundle:RelationEntity r
JOIN r.superclassId c
WHERE
c INSTANCE OF BasicBundle:Subclass
```

My problem is that I also want to set a WHERE Clause with an attribute of the subclass like this:

```
WHERE
c INSTANCE OF BasicBundle:Subclass
AND
c.subclassAttribute LIKE %example%
```

This doesn't work. I did some research and found [this article](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-16) but everytime I try to use a "CAST" in my queries I get an error. So it seems like that CAST isn't available.

Does anyone know how to use a subclass attribute in the WHERE statement of a superclasses query?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with a subquery?

E.g.:

```
WHERE
c INSTANCE OF BasicBundle:Subclass
AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT x FROM BasicBundle:Subclass s 
   WHERE s.id = c.id AND s.subclassAttribute LIKE %example%)
```

Maybe I did something wrong with instances, but honestly you did not provided a very detailed example.